# How can i load this url image into an imageview i tried Glide and image loader but didnt work

Tags: android, url, android-glide

URL - https://qrco.de/bbUCkW

Code -    Glide.with(ScanningActivity.this).load("https://qrco.de/bbUCkW").into(img);

didnt work out.

please help me with loading this url image into imageview.

Comment: please post the error log trace which you received.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the image address https://qrco.de/bbUCkW

Glide only loads images and converts them into a bitmap for android. It cannot load the website. You need to provide a valid image URL,
here is the correct URL of [image](https://qrcgcustomers.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/account8130921/6716573_1.png?0.7500747721711662).

```
Glide.with(ScanningActivity.this).load("https://qrcgcustomers.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/account8130921/6716573_1.png?0.7500747721711662").into(img);
```

Comment: i tried this also but wat is the solution for this https://qrco.de/bbUCkW url if i need to set imageview , actually after scannning qr code i m geting this url and want to set image into imageview

Comment: this is the link of page u need to get imageurl then provide this imageurl to glide to load image

Comment: okayy i will get the image url

Answer (score 0):

I think you are providing an url of a whole webpage, glide only loads image from url and converts it to bitmap, if you need to load the image in the middle of the web page you will need to provide the image url that is right now I can see [this](https://qrcgcustomers.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/account8130921/6716573_1.png?0.7500747721711662).

Comment: yes i know that but wat is the solution for this url , i need to change it or somethingelse?

Comment: Use a WebView to display the html page.

Comment: @AshwinJawale are you getting the license image from some api? or do you need to whole webpage on android?

Comment: i only want image url

Comment: @AshwinJawale where are you getting the image url? do you have access to api?

Comment: no its just a qr code generator site.

Comment: after scanning qr code from phone the image will come?

Comment: no its just returning the url as this- https://qrco.de/bbUCkW in logcat

Comment: can i get image url from the webpage then? @suvodipMondal

Comment: Do you have the access to the data on your phone that is coming on the website??